# The specified time and date run sql script or store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to run a sql script or store procedure at specified time and date which get from a table in database. If this table have a row was inserted or update the schedule would be updated. Please help me!

Comment: One way is scheduling an operative system task (start-accessories-system tools-scheduled tasks) where you call the “sqlcmd” shell command to perform a query

the second one is programming a new job on sql server management studio (sql server agent – jobs new) with a transact-sql step with the command.

Comment: Create an agent job that always fires, repeatedly *(maybe every 5minutes, maybe every hour)*. But the start of that job, check the contents of your table. If there is nothing to do, quit. If there is something to do, do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a job with the SQL Server Agent.

[image]

Then you will right-click on the Jobs folder to open the menu, select New Job:

[image]

When you create a new job a window will open and you will provide the details of you job that you want to create. Including:

- Name - in the General tab
- Steps - can run a SQL script, SSIS package, etc
- Schedule - recurring, weekly, daily, etc. at the frequency that you pick.

[Step By Step Guide to creating a SQL Job](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/step_by_step_guide_to_add_a_sql_job_in_sql_server_2005.aspx)

Comment: How can i update schedule by sql script?